# Spotify web link search

Tags: search, web, hyperlink, spotify

We currently list the [tracks played by our DJs on-air](https://radio.abc.net.au/stations/triplej/live). Next to each track we provide the option to open the track in YouTube, Spotify and Google. At the moment there is no one-to-one mapping from our track list to an entry in those 3rd party databases (we don't have an ID for those respective systems) meaning we perform a simple search on the artist and track name. This might therefore return zero or multiple entries.

Our Spotify link looks something like this:

```
https://open.spotify.com/search/artist:Remi%20track:Sangria
```

We've just noticed that all these links seem to be broken - Spotify just returns a web page saying "Sorry, couldn't find that". I'm struggling to find any information online about this. Does anyone know if Spotify changed their API recently and what we can do to fix these URLs?

Comment: I think you are right. These links used to work, so the API for the open site must have changed. I can notify someone and see if I can get it fixed.

Comment: any updates on your solution? I noticed it still hasn't been resolved on your live playlist.

Comment: No update sorry

Comment: Still nothing? I think it would be to the benefit of Spotify (as well as my users and thus me) if web apps can link to songs / search results?

Answer (score 3):

Not quite a like-for-like replacement but we've noticed that using the domain "play.spotify.com" rather than "open.spotify.com" will at least perform the track search on the Spotify web player:

```
https://play.spotify.com/search/artist:Remi%20track:Sangria
```

It would be good to know how we can open the desktop player though using a search.

Just as additional info, I'm hoping that we change our track ingestion process to look up the details in the Spotify database to determine the track id or uri and store this in our API. Then we can display the track link to the user to avoid using a search mechanism on the front-end.